# c sharp не запускается событие WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged

Tags: c#

Вот такой код выполняется в отдельном классе(не статический, но экземпляр один) в таске:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
DownloaderGroupBoxItem dgbi = new DownloaderGroupBoxItem(video.title, gbDownloadingPanel);
Token token = new Token(video, dgbi);
wc.DownloadProgressChanged += Wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
wc.DownloadFileCompleted += Wc_DownloadFileCompleted;
string filePath = GetPathForVideoFile(group.name, album.title, video.title);
wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(videoUrl), filePath, token);
webClients.Add(wc);
Log.WriteInFile("Загружаем...");
//ожидаем свободные потоки
while (webClients.Count >= threadsCount) ;
```

Вот событие(находится в том же классе):

```
        public void Wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient wc = (WebClient)sender;
        webClients.Remove(wc);
        Token token = (Token)e.UserState;
        token.dgbi.Remove();
        Log.WriteInDownloader("Успешно скачали " + token.video.title);
    }
```

Проставилял брейкпоинты. Объект wc на события подписывается. Но ни один из брейкпоинтов в событии не отозвался. Файлы качаются(появляются в папке). 
С событием Wc_DownloadProgressChanged та же беда.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Comment: Вероятно, поток занят циклом `while`. Избавьтесь от него.

Comment: Так... ну допустим в этом проблема... а как тогда ограничить кол-во потоков?

Comment: Вроде помогло. Но теперь не ясно как ограничивать кол-во потоков...

Comment: @АлександрЛи: Непонятен смысл всей операции. Чего вы хотите достигнуть? Что означает «ограничить количество потоков» и как оно достигается в вашем коде?

Comment: Я так понимаю, создаётся множество потоков и в каждом создаётся свой `WebClient`. Это неверное решение. При использовании асинхронного метода достаточно одного потока.

Comment: У меня есть цикл, в котором создаются WebClientы для каждого файла. Каждый веблиент я сохраняю в глобальный лист. В конце каждой итеракции проверяю не превышает ли кол-во вебклиентов в глобальном листе - установленного заранее кол-ва потоков.

Comment: Решится ли проблема, если я буду создавать вебклиенты заранее, а позже отдельным потоком буду выдавать им задачи. Будут ли вебклиенты рапортавать о событиях, если поток раздающий задачи висит на while?

Comment: Не понимаю в чем проблема. Т.к. есть в другом приложении точно такая же реализация скачивания файла. Там события работают. Разница лишь в том, что работающее приложение построенно на wpf, а не работающее на winForm...